# Embedding DIV using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here the div's which i used to show 2 pop up's depending on the below mentioned ajax method reponse,

```
 <a href="#flash" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" class="auto-pop" data-transition="none"></a>
 <div data-role="popup" id="flash" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="c" data-dismissible="false" class="ui-content" class="dc">
 <center><img src="images/spin.gif" width="250" height="268" /></center>
 <p class="dc"><strong>Congratulations you have achieved <span class="percentage_value"> </span>% of the readings!</strong></p>
 </div>

 <a href="#achievflash" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" class="auto-pop1" data-transition="none"></a>
 <div data-role="popup" id="achievflash" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="c" class="ui-content" class="dc">
 <p class="dc"><strong>This is a free app.</p><p> Please<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b">DONATE</a> for us.
 </strong></p>



 if(achieve.flag == 1) {
    setTimeout(function(){
     $('.percentage_value').text(achieve_value); $('#flash').show();
     $('#flash-screen').show();
     $('a.auto-pop').trigger('click');
     $('#flash').delay(4000).fadeOut(1000);
     $('#flash-screen').delay(4000).fadeOut(1000);
    },100);
    }//flag if
if(donation.flag == 1) {
    setTimeout(function(){
     $('#achievflash').show();
     $('#achievflash-screen').show();
     $('a.auto-pop1').trigger('click');
    },6000);
}
```

I have around 100 different html files ,each contains the same above div.I want to make the div as in one js and call it as method.Please help me to resolve how i can acheive this

Answer (score 1):

You can `append` / `prepend` your html directly thru JS:

```
var html;
html += '<a href="#flash" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" class="auto-pop" data-transition="none"></a>';
html += '<div data-role="popup" id="flash" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="c" data-dismissible="false" class="ui-content" class="dc">';
html += '  <center><img src="images/spin.gif" width="250" height="268" /></center>';
html += '  <p class="dc"><strong>Congratulations you have achieved <span class="percentage_value"> </span>% of the readings!</strong></p>';
html += '</div>';
```

And then:

```
$("body").prepend(html);
```

**OR** You should better put your Content in one tag, appending that tag first and after this Content to that tag. You fill get pointer by you can handle attributes. For example:

```
var pointer = $('<span></span>');
$(pointer).append(html);
$("body").prepend(pointer);
```

And now you can control you html thru `pointer`. E.g:

```
 $(pointer).fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

1. In every of your pages remove your div's. Add only script reference with your logic.

   `<script src="//code.jquery.com/your-script.js"></script>`
2. Make two files on your server "your-script.js" (with showing popup logic) and "your-content.html" (with contents of your div only).
3. Modify "your-script.js" so it will be able to load remote html content from "your-content.html" file and insert raw HTML data into desired place on any page:

   `$("#body").load("/path/to/your-content.html");`

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure which div you are referring to, however, the best way to make a certain div appear would be to store the div as a JS variable and use the jQuery `.append()` or `.prepend()` method to add it to the page.

As long as the JS file is included on every page, you will be able to append the div's easily.

Example HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv">This is the existing division</div>
```

Example JavaScript / jQuery:

```
var newDiv = "<div id='newDiv'>This is your new div</div>"
var differentDiv = "<div id='differentDiv'>This is a different new div</div>"

if (/*response 1*/) {
    $("#myDiv").append(newDiv); //Could also append to $("body")
} else if (/*response 2*/) {
    $("#myDiv").append(differentDiv); //Could also append to $("body")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways to do this.

You could make that code a variable in your JS and pull it in that way.

```
var code = '<a href="#flash" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" class="auto-pop"     data-transition="none"></a>     <div data-role="popup" id="flash" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="c" data-    dismissible="false" class="ui-content" class="dc">     <center><img src="images/spin.gif" width="250" height="268" /></center>     <p class="dc"><strong>Congratulations you have achieved <span class="percentage_value">     </span>% of the readings!</strong></p>     </div>     <a href="#achievflash" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" class="auto-pop1" data-transition="none"></a>     <div data-role="popup" id="achievflash" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="c" class="ui-content" class="dc">     <p class="dc"><strong>This is a free app.</p><p> Please<a href="https://afes.org.au/events/donate-to-stand-firm" target="_blank" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b">DONATE</a> for us.     </strong></p>'

$('html').append(code);
```

OR

```
$('div').after(code);
```

to insert after a specific selector.

---

You could also put it an its own file and include it with either HTML or PHP includes.

HTML INCLUDE:

```
<!--#include virtual="filepath" -->
```

PHP INCLUDE:

```
<?php include("filepath"); ?>
```

where "filepath" is the path to the file containing the code.

Comment: Html out of the `Body` tag is invalid and this quetion is without `PHP`, see tags.